# Automate ssh port forwarding using DNS

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, ssh-tunnel, dynamic-dns

I have a number of ssh hosts (a dozen), for simplicity `host1`, `host2`, etc.

I frequently need to forward port, e.g.

```
ssh -L 8888:localhost:8888 host1
ssh -L 8889:localhost:8888 host2
ssh -L 8890:localhost:80   host2
```

This is annoying since 1) I need to remember mapping from local ports to hosts and 2) I need to do that manually

I'd like to implement some kind of system that listened to specific hosts (locally, on my machine), e.g. `host1.8888.ssh.local` and opened tunnel to this address automatically.

Comment: Sounds like adding a few static hostnames via `/etc/hosts` and defining the localport/remoteport associations via systemd socket activation could automate this..

Comment: @anx sounds very reasonable

Answer (score 4):

You can configure all this stuff inside the ssh config file, usually found at the location: `$HOME/.ssh/config`

for example:

```
Host abc
    Hostname 1.2.3.4
    Port 345
    IdentityFile /path/to/id_rsa
    LocalForward 8888 localhost:8888
    User root
Host def
    Hostname 2.3.4.5
    User root
    LocalForward 8889 localhost:8889
```

This way, you just need to type `ssh abc` and all your settings you specify inside there will get applied. Available Options found inside the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware about this option in ssh configs. It doesn't solve main points: memorization of ports and manual opening of ports

Comment: What do you mean by "manual opening of ports"? And I don't see why this wouldn't solve the "memorization of ports" problem? The ports are stored in the configuration, and you need to only remember the host names you assign in the config.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen is correct. Even if you forgot the assigned host name, you could still simply take a look into the config to check what hosts you defined there.

Comment: That means - you still need to ssh. Tunnel should be opened automatically

Comment: `remember the host names you assign in the config` correct, this step should be eliminated. For the user (in this example - me) it should be possible to use machine hostname to use tunnel

Comment: As already said, you can use whatever you want as Host definition name - so it is totally fine to use the machine hostname inside the Host definition. You got everything you need, to automate this, you just need to put all ssh commands (with ```-fN``` ) inside a script, and place that script inside your startup files...

Comment: As already said, I am well-aware of ssh configs. Keeping a dozen of connections doesn't sound like a great idea to me. When notebook is started, there may be no internet at all, because I can be on a train. System should work for multiple users and allow them non memorizing ports (moreover set not by them).

Comment: I can reiterate: this solution has nothing to do with requirements set in the question

Answer (score 1):

I developed [sshtunnel](https://github.com/yurt-page/sshtunnel) that is a service that will establish tunnels and keep them running.

```
server "srv_us"
  HostName="srv.us"
  User="root"
  IdentityFile="/root/.ssh/id_ed25519"

tunnelR "srv_us_http"
  servername="srv_us"
  remoteaddress="1"
  remoteport=80
  localaddress="127.0.0.1"
  localport=8080
```

If you have an OpenWrt router you can use a similar [sshtunnel](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/ssh/sshtunnel) service. Recently was added a GUI to configure it luci-app-sshtunnel.

Answer (score 1):

A note from the future, which has nothing to do with the question asked, but solved underlying problem.

If you do things in vs code on the server, after you start any process (e.g. jupyter, tensorboard, dashboards, webservers), vs code forwards those ports to local machine, so no need to memorize anything, the ports are forwarded only from the host you currently work with - and any number of ports, and only used ports. What a convenience!